# Using Fermat’s Little Theorem to calculate the remainder of a very large exponential

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, exponential-function

"What is the remainder of $3^{12194}$ when divided by 17?"

So I'm trying to work this out using Fermat’s Little Theorem which I know we can use for a fact because 17 is prime with  GCD(3,17)=1 and I've tried using it and other questionable methods to at least calculate the remainder of $3^{12194}$ before doing the division part but I just keep getting incorrect answers and quite frankly I have no idea as to why. Would appreciate it if someone could show how this is supposed to be done correctly.

Comment: “FLT” is usually understood (in the number theory context) to stand for Fermat’s **Last** Theorem; what you want here is probably the so-called “Fermat’s **Little** Theorem”, which is *never* abbreviated “FLT”. (And in other contexts, ‘flt’ may stand for “Faster than Light Travel”).

Comment: You mean $3^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{17}$, then $12194=16\times762+2$ hence $3^{12194}\equiv{3^{16}}^{762}\cdot3^2\equiv 9\pmod{17}$?

Comment: There are several duplicates to this popular question. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) explains it in general, other ones give some more examples to use little Fermat and other methods.